# Hadoop + Hive - hcatalog won't startup

Tags: hive, hcatalog

I just installed a single node Hadoop 2.2.0 cluster running on ubuntu.
I tried a couple of basic example calculations and it works fine.

I then tried to setup hive 0.12.0, that includes hcatalog.

I actually follow this [tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallationandConfiguration).

And when I try to start hcatalog, I always get the following error :

> bash $HIVE_HOME/hcatalog/sbin/hcat_server.sh start
>
> dirname: missing operand
>   Try `dirname --help' for more information.
>   Started metastore server init, testing if initialized correctly...
>
> /usr/local/hive/hcatalog/sbin/hcat_server.sh: line 91: /usr/local/hive-0.12.0/hcatalog/sbin/../var/log/hcat.out: No such file or directory
>
> Metastore startup failed, see /usr/local/hive-0.12.0/hcatalog/sbin/../var/log/hcat.err

But there's no hcat.err file at all, I'm kind of blocked right now.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Thanks in advance,

Guillaume

Comment: me too, in hive-0.13:

Answer (score 1):

I worked out that hcat was not executable in the hive installation I have downloaded.

S just sudo chmod A+X hcat and it works